# Medalhas que dependem de tags

Tags: suporte, tags, medalhas

Estava a olhar as medalhas e uma dúvida me surgiu: o que acontece com uma pessoa que ganha uma medalha - [esta é um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/91/html) - que depende de uma tag e autor da postagem remove a tag em uma edição?

Isso claro, num ponto que faça o recompensado pela medalha ficar fora do alcance do recompensamento(?) da medalha.

Comment: Acho que depois de ganhares a medalha, ninguém ta tira.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No caso das medalhas de tags, elas podem ser "confiscadas" [caso você passe a não satisfazer mais os critérios para seu recebimento](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/177950) (como apontado por @brasofilo nos comentários) - ao contrário das medalhas "normais", que uma vez que você ganha elas são suas pra sempre.

De acordo com esses [dois](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110675/177950) [posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30193/177950) no MSE, retagear uma pergunta afeta sim as medalhas. No caso, era a discussão de um abuso - *acrescentar* tags para se ganhar mais medalhas - mas pela lógica isso deve funcionar pros dois lados: ao se remover uma tag da pergunta, um usuário que a respondeu pode perder a medalha. Seria bom ter uma confirmação "oficial", mas para todos os efeitos esse deve ser o comportamento esperado na ausência de informação em contrário.

Comment: As medalhas de tags [podem ser removidas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/185667), minha dúvida é quanto ao re-tagging de uma pergunta. Provavelmente remove também.

Comment: Sim @brasofilo, retags removem também. Medalhas de tag são as únicas que são removidas (exceto em caso de fraude, aí as normais podem acabar removidas também).